# How do I detect if an input isn't a letter? I am writing a game and it needs to print "not valid input"

Tags: java

I am writing a game and I want to warn the player if the input isn't a letter?. For example, if the input is '(' or '6', it needs to print "not valid input". I also need "!" to be a valid input as a way to end the game.

The following is a demo of the game.

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+

Secret Phrase:   ---
Guessed Letters: 
Enter a letter to guess or "!" to end the game
(
No, ( is not in the phrase
```

The following is the coding part

```
while (gameEnd == false) {
    System.out.println(drawScoreboard(totalGuesses, wrong));
    System.out.println("Enter a letter to guess or \"!\" to end the game");
    letterz = scnr.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < secretPhrase.length(); i++) {
        for (int hk = 0; hk < alreadyGuessed.length(); hk++) {
            if (Character.toString(letterz.charAt(0)).equals(Character.toString(alreadyGuessed.charAt(hk)))) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i >= letterz.length()) {
            break;
        } else if ((Character.toString(letterz.charAt(i))).equalsIgnoreCase(Character.toString(secretPhrase.charAt(i)))) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            inc++;
        } else if (letterz.equals("!")) {
            gameEnd = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No, " + letterz + " is not in the phrase\n");
            wrong++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic(int)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to check if a string matches a particular pattern of characters is with the method `String.matches`. For example:

```
guess.matches("[A-Z!]+")
```

will return true if and only if `guess` only contains uppercase letters or the `!` character.